# UITableView background as tiled image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have an image which height is about 1,5 screen on iPhone. I want to make it as a continuous background of UITableView. It have to scroll with the table. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You could turn this image into a pattern that can then be repeated indefinitely as the background of the table view. First, do this:

```
UIColor *backgroundPatternColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:myImage];
```

Then set the background color of your table view, or any other view for that matter, to `backgroundPatternColor`.

Comment: You should set table view's background view to nil in order for the background color to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

There is simple solution.

Use this code to set background pattern image for table view (pattern image may be small image, which you would like to tile):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back"]];
}
```

Tiled image will be tiled infinite both up and down and scrolled with tableView.

Then do next important trick - set transparent background color to cells, because setting tableView backgroundColor also sets tiled backgrounds to cells:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Use this approach for simple tableView cells, otherwise transparent backgrounds of complex cells yields performance lack.

Answer (score 1):

Table view scrolling is largely an illusion in that table cells are queued when not being used and dequeued when a new one is needed again when the user swipes/scrolls it. We often refer to this as a treadmill effect where what you are seeing on the screen is like the belt of a treadmill. It exists only within the viewport and doesn't actually scroll any farther though it appears otherwise. This means that your table view's background image will be *pinned* in place and not scroll with your cells.

I think the only way to do what you're wanting where the images scrolls with your cells would be to break your image up into pieces the size of your cells and set the background of each cell to the image for that index path.

so say you have a table view that's something like this:

```
         CELLS            INDEX PATH
|----------------------|
|          |           |  0, 0
|----------------------|
|        /   \         |  0, 1
|----------------------|
|      YOUR IMAGE      |  0, 2
|----------------------|
|        HERE          |  0, 3
|----------------------|
|        \   /         |  0, 4
|----------------------|
```

Pre-slice your image into equal size parts that are the correct height for your cells. Then, you could just grab the row of the index path in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and set the cell's background image based on that. You may eventually run out of images if you have more cells than you have image height, however, this would be pretty easy to check for.

If you named your images something like background_0.png, background_1.png, etc., you could grab the image you need like this:

```
UIImage *imageForCell = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"background_%d", [indexPath row]]];
[[cell backgroundImageView] setImage:imageForCell];
```

Where `backgroundImageView` is an image view you added to a custom cell.

Comment: Hell Yeah! This is the idea! I have to distribute image pieces equally, regarding to start new image when the old ends! I will think about it tomorrow. Thanks mate!

Comment: I am afraid that this wont work when I have the images above the table  and these have to have background either. I mean there have to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a tiled, scrolling background for your table. The UI that you would usually use for something that scrolls in tiles is a table. So use a table for your background :)

You need two tables: a backgroundTableView and a contentTableView. The contentTableView is whatever you need it to be, but make sure you set the cells' and table's background colors and views to clear/nil.

The backgroundTableView contains your tiled images: that is, every cell should be the height of your tiled image, and should contain your tiled image.

Then when you scroll the contentTableView, update the contentOffset of the backgroundTableView to match:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (scrollView == self.contentTableView) {
        self.backgroundTableView.contentOffset = self.contentTableView.contentOffset;
    }
}
```

Make sure you set your controller up as the dataSource and delegate for both tables. Also, make sure you have enough "content" (number of rows * height) in the backgroundTableView that it can continue to scroll until at least the end of the contentTableView.

Aaaaaand done!

Comment: I suspect it means that my contentTableView should be forced to be first responder, and then push its contentOffset to backgroundTableView

Comment: err, I'm not sure: I don't know what it would mean for a UITableView to be first responder. I want to say no, but I don't think it matters. Just make sure that the two tables have the same frame, and are subviews of the same view (the background should be behind the content). And yes, the contentTableView is the only one that will respond to events. This does work BTW, I tried it before posting.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView inherits from UIScrollView. I recommend you add your image as a custom subview of the UITableView hierarchy.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[self.tableView insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
```

Now, you may need to subclass UITableView and provide your own implementation of

```
    - (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self sendSubviewToBack:myImageView];
}
```

I just pulled this code out of the top of my head, so you may need to fiddle with it.

Answer (score -1):

Your could just set your image as the table's background view.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_BACKGROUND_IMAGE"]];
```

Comment: Not if he wants to tile it.  That stretches the image to fill the whole background.